# How to inherit function options

Tags: clojure

I wrote this function that gets an element out of a tree.  It's just this:

```
(defn at [address tree] (reduce nth tree address))
```

Now the problem with this is that `nth` has 2 overloads; one that throws an exception if the index is out of range, and one that takes a `not-found` argument to return instead of throwing and exception.

Now I could make an overload for my function to add this option like so:

```
(defn at [address tree not-found] 
  (reduce (fn [curr-tree index] (nth curr-tree index not-found))
          tree address))
```

I could complain about how I have to explicitly make a new function instead of the nice `nth` by itself.

This isn't the real problem though.  I shouldn't have to make an overload for every overload that `nth` has.

`nth` only has two overloads, but for other times when I want to write a wrapper-like function, how can I defer decisions to the user.  In this example, I'm just wrapping `nth`; to be consistent, I want `at` to imitate the behavior of `nth`. How do I inherit the options of other functions?

I'm asking this from a clojure point of view, but it may or may not apply to other languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you design `at` in terms of `nth`'s design? Whoever calls `at` shouldn't be thinking about `nth`'s overloads.

`at` can be passed a function like in @amalloy's answer. But I would suggest starting with a simpler design and refactoring later if need be:

```
(defn at
  ([address tree]
    (reduce nth tree address))
  ([address tree not-found]
    (reduce #(nth %1 %2 not-found) tree address)))
```

My rationale is passing a `not-found` value is easier to understand than passing a function:

```
(def maybe-x (at addr tree :bummer))

;; See @amalloy's answer
(def maybe-x (at' addr tree #(nth %1 %2 :bummer))))
```

In fact if I need to pass some other function later, I would make a new `at-by` function (see [group-by](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/group-by)).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this?

```
(defn at [address tree & more]
  (reduce (fn [a i] (apply nth a i more)) tree address))
```

The `& more` picks up whatever extra arguments the user might supply, and the `apply` sticks them on to the end of the call to `nth`, without you having to worry about what `nth` is going to do with them.

Stylistically, though, I'd prefer to write out the overloads. It will make for better documentation of what options your function supports, and it will be easier to maintain down the road.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a function argument to call instead of nth, and then you don't care how many overloads it has, because the caller will handle the one overload they actually want to use.

```
(defn at
  ([address tree]
     (at address tree nth))
  ([address tree f]
     (reduce f tree address)))

(at [whatever] some-tree #(nth % %2 nil))
```